# Is it possible to extend an existing Objective-C Block?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, objective-c-blocks

I have a class using a Block defined in the header like this:

```
@property (readwrite, copy) RequestSucceededBlock succeededBlock;
```

The property `succeededBlock` is already set with a Block. Is there a way to override this Block with another that still calls the original, similar to class inheritance?

I assume this is not possible, because class inheritance should be used to express things like that. Is it still possible?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, make another copy of the former block somewhere accessible, and call it from the latter block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about trying to have a replacement block in a subclass that still calls the superclass block, you can't inject a block into an existing block but you can fake it as follows:

```
// in MySubclass.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) RequestSucceededBlock subclassSucceededBlock;

// in MySubclass.m
- (RequestSucceededBlock)succeededBlock
{
    [return subclassSucceededBlock];
}

- (void)setSucceededBlock:(RequestSucceededBlock)newSucceededBlock
{
    // make sure this conforms to the definition of RequestSucceededBlock
    RequestSucceededBlock combinedBlock = ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), newSucceededBlock);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), [super succeededBlock]);
    };
    subclassSucceededBlock = combinedBlock;
}
```

This is a bit odd though b/c it assumes the superclass has a default block assigned to `succeededBlock` that you want to dispatch. If your question has a different use in mind please clarify and I'll see if I can update this.

EDIT: added `copy` to iVar

Comment: Shouldn't the combinedBlock block be copied into the iVar ?

Comment: I'm looking forward to trying this out.  I think, all things considered, it's about as elegant as you can get... great answer.