# Call a super block / extending a block

Tags: objective-c, subclass, objective-c-blocks

I've subclassed a class, which holds a block property, I need to extend.

The superclass's property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) id (^willMapDeserializedResponseBlock)(id deserializedResponseBody);
```

Every time this block gets set I need to extend the block by my own code/block.

Basically this is what I want to do in my subclass:

```
[self setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:^id(id deserializedResponseBody) {

    // original block

    // do my own stuff 

    return deserializedResponseBody;
}];
```

How do I implement something like this?
I've found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041825/1873085) to a similar question but it didn't helped me, maybe because of the return value of the block?

Comment: How can the super class even have a block?  Please supply some example usage of calling this method.

Comment: and who would receive the returned `deserializedResponseBody` in your idea?

Comment: @Droppy The superclass itself sets this block as well, with its own implementation but I need to add some own stuff.

Comment: Please provide more code/class definitions to clarify.

Comment: OK, perhaps I expressed myself wrong

Comment: @Droppy I've just updated my question hopefully this makes things clearer. Hard to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't add code to an existing Block, but you can easily adapt the solution from the question you linked:

```
- (void)setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:(id(^)(id))willMapDeserializedResponseBlock
{
    id (^additionalCode)(id, id) = ^id (id deserializedResponseBody, id originalReturnVal){
        // Do your own stuff
        return whatever;
    };

    id (^newWillMapBlock)(id) = ^id (id deserializedResponseBody){
        id retVal = willMapDeserializedResponseBlock(deserializedResponseBody);
        return additionalCode(deserializedResponseBody, retVal);
    };

    _willMapDeserializedResponseBlock = newWillMapBlock;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it unusual to run the block in a setter method?

Comment: I'd say so, but none of the Blocks are being called here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I slightly modified the code but it works like a charm!